# Tag synonym for alternative spelling of "behavior"

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonyms

I just saw an [edit in the review queue](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/81983) which changed the tag [behaviour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaviour) to [behavior](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior), and rightfully so. As Glorfindel pointed out in the edit, SE guidance indicates that [tags should be in US-English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us/23873#23873). I've proposed a synonym for these tags so that it will automatically change to the correct spelling in the future. It just needs four more votes to go into effect. Please vote for it [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/behavior/synonyms)!

Comment: Now that is a horse of a different colour.  I can see no defence in it's usage.

Comment: Both ways of spelling are correct in English IIRC... just like "color" and "colour", etc.

Comment: @Richard U: [*"it's"* is not British spelling](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s)

Comment: @PeterMortensen er, huh?  A baking powder?  Exsqueeze me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The synonym has now been approved. Thanks!